# Accessing array outside of a PS function

Tags: powershell

I am having a hard time figuring out how to get the PSCustomObject/array out of the function.  I have tried using $Global:ZipList as well as just passing the variables into an array directly w/o a custom object but no luck.  The reason I need this, is I need to then loop through the array/list after I get the filenames and then was going to loop through this list and unzip each file and log it and process it based on the extension in the zip; this is to be used for multiple zips, so I can't predetermine the file extensions without grabbing the filenames in the zip into a list.  I would just use a shell however some of the zips are password protected, haven't figured out how to pass a password scripted to the shell com unzip windows feature so stuck with 7z for now.  Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

```
Function ReadZipFile([string]$ZipFileName)
{
[string[]]$ReadZipFile = & 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' l "$ZipFileName"
[bool]$separatorFound = $false
#$ZipList = @()
$ReadZipFile | ForEach-Object{
    if ($_.StartsWith("------------------- ----- ------------ ------------")) 
    {

        if ($separatorFound)
        {
          BREAK  # Second separator; We're done!
        }
    $separatorFound = -not $separatorFound
    } 
    else
    {
        if ($separatorFound)
        {
            [DateTime]$FileCreatedDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Substring(0, 19),"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss", [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
            [Int]$FileSize = [Int]"0$($_.Substring(26, 12).Trim())"
            $ZipFileName = $_.Substring(53).TrimEnd()

           $ZipList = [PSCustomObject] @{
                                              ZipFileName=$ZipFileName
                                              FileCreatedDate=$FileCreatedDate
                                              FileSize=$FileSize}
        } 
    }   
} 
}
$z = ReadZipFile $ZipFileName 

$ZipList | Select-Object ZipFileName
```

To be able to select from array created in the function outside of it. I believe my if statements may be blocking the global variable feature when i tried using global:

Comment: Remove the $ziplist = assignment. Just output the pscustomobject. Then $z will contain your array

Comment: Thanks for that help.  Here is my revised code.  Now I am questioning the psobject route. I am guessing no, but is there any way to expand more than 1 property?  If not, is there a better solution than using a psobject/custom object?  once it's out of the function, I would like to be able to access the 3 values in the array.

Comment: DUH@! Foreach-object.   Sorry to waste anyone's time on something so simple.  Sometimes I just get lost in this stuff after looking at it too long.